# Trying to post a variable from js to php within a if clause

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to post a variable within a if clause, but the php document is not receiving the variable. 
Here is some Code:

JS:

```
if(data.details.payment_type =="sofo")    {
    var orderid = data.details.order_id;
    $.post("LinkToPhpDocument.php", { orderidvalue: orderid });
    window.location.replace("LinkToPhpDocument.php");
}
```

PHP

```
$orderID = $_POST['orderidvalue'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for Ajax ended then redirect user:

```
if(data.details.payment_type =="sofo")    {
    var orderid = data.details.order_id;
    $.post("LinkToPhpDocument.php", { orderidvalue: orderid },function(res){
        window.location.replace("LinkToPhpDocument.php");
    });
}
```

Comment: @DeltaJohn sure you're not getting php error 500 or you're imported jquery

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
if(data.details.payment_type =="sofo")    {
    var orderid = data.details.order_id;   
        $.ajax({
            url: 'LinkToPhpDocument.php', 
            type: POST,      
            data: 'orderidvalue='+orderid,     
            cache: false,
            success: function(res){                          
                window.location.replace("LinkToPhpDocument.php");
            }
          })
       }
```

**Note :** It will only replace the window location not redirect you to the `LinkToPhpDocument.php` page.It navigates to the URL without adding a new record to the history.